# Issue writing to an outfile in ruby

Tags: ruby, io

Is there some trick to writing to an outfile in windows using ruby? I'm using the following:

```
f = File.new(filename, 'r+')
f.puts detailed_html
f.close
```

And I get the error:

> No such file or directory.

This alternative gives the same error:

```
f = File.open(filename, 'r+')
```

I am 1000% positive that `filename` is a value file path, the files don't exist yet; i want the script to create them.

**Note:** If I create the files -- with the proper names -- manually prior to running the script, it works. How do you get ruby to either overwrite an existing file, or create the file if it doesn't exist on windows??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1581674/10396 for a good explanation of 'r+' vs 'w+'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to be extra sure to overwrite existing file or create a new one.

```
f = File.new(filename, File::CREAT|File::TRUNC|File::RDWR)
```

this should do just about the same

```
f = File.new(filename, 'w+')
```

Comment: ugh, they should mention that in r+ (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html), i didn't read down to w+ because i thought i'd found it

Comment: @NMoney: since you've found the answer yourself, this question should be deleted probably.

Comment: No need to delete it, just accept the right answer so other searchers can find it here.