# How can I write a ruby program to implement a modes of file?

Tags: ruby

I write the following code but it gives the error. No such file or directory - sample.txt (Errno::ENOENT).

```
File.new("sample.txt","r")
File.new("tepm.txt","r+") 
File.new("new_temp.txt","w")
File.new("new_sample.txt","w+")
File.new("example.txt","a")
File.new("new_example.txt","a+")


file = File.open("sample.txt","w+")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between the access modes of the \`File\` object (ie. w+, r+)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581674/difference-between-the-access-modes-of-the-file-object-ie-w-r)

Comment: *"... implement a mode of file"* - can you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you looking for [`File::chmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html#method-c-chmod)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you try to open file (only for read) which does not exist.

Create file manually or use `w+` flag to let script create it for you for reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is trying to read sample.txt but you don't have the file in the same directory as the script. Make a file in that same directory with the name "sample.txt" and it should work.